# D3js linear color scale with custom values (ticks)?

Tags: d3.js, maps

**Background concept:** Elevation maps and their color keys for human readers require a more detailed coverage of lower elevation (<200m), where 80% of the world population lives.

**D3 project:**

Given such elevations threshold levels (m) as : 0, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000m.

1. Based on a **linear color scale**
2. **ticks every 20px (regular span)**
3. **color picking at specific thresholds:** 0, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000m
4. **ticks with specific labels:** 0, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000m

Examples of such custom scale, scale.ordinal(), scale.log(), etc. welcome.

---

**Comment:** I currently goes with an unsatisfying linear ramp code, [see this](https://codio.io/hugolpz/D3-map/topography.html), which cut my scale into 10 **equal** spans of 500m :

[image]

I should actually have 4 differents greens standing for 0, 50, 100, and 200m and less browns/greys/whites.

1. Var color declaration. Set up the color ramp table by stating the points where I have color shifts :

```
// Color-values equivalence
var color_elev = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, 200, 2000, 5000]) // values elevation (m)
  .range(["#ACD0A5", "#E1E4B5", "#AA8753", "#FFFFFF"]) // colors
  .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl)
```

each of these 3 spans should indeed have linear color changes.

2. Injection of my SVG polygons

```
// Data (getJSON: TopoJSON)
d3.json("data/topo/final.json", showData);
// ---------- FUNCTION ------------- //
function showData(error, fra) {
 ... // do my topojson to svg map injection
}
```

3. Create, push my Color ramp box and key

```
/* START LEGEND_RAMP  */
// Color ramp
var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, 5000]) // legend elevation (m)
  .range([0, 280]); // width (px)

// Color ramp place  ? ? ?
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")
  .tickSize(13)
  .tickFormat(d3.format(".0f"));

// (JS shortcut)
var legend_key = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend_key")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width - 300) + "," + (height - 30) + ")");

// Color ramp: white background
legend_key.append("rect")
  .attr("x", -10)
  .attr("y", -10)
  .attr("width", 310)
  .attr("height", 40)
  .style("fill", "white")
  .style("fill-opacity", 0.5)

// Color ramp: bricks
legend_key.selectAll(".color_ramp")
  .data(d3.pairs(x.ticks(10))) // is this forcing a 10 equal sizes slicing ?
.enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "elev_color_brick") // or "band"
  .attr("height", 8)
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d[0]); })
  .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d[1]) - x(d[0]); })
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color_elev(d[0]); });

// ?
legend_key.call(xAxis);
/* END LEGEND  */
```

Comment: Seems [this Kentucky Population Density blocks](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5144735) may be an helpful example with a threshold() approach.

Answer (score 1):

I'd comment this, but can't at present, have you looked at [colorbrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/)? Also, have you considered using an [ordinal scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales).  You'd be able to control the colour ramp by mapping ranges to particular colours.  If you're looking for a more automated way you could use an equal area distribution (histogram equalisation) method? Otherwise power or log scales could be an improvement over linear.

Comment: **1. Colorbrewer:** I have for now to respect an existing color ramp already in use. But I keep colorbrewer in mind. **2. Scale:**
I was not aware of `ordinal scales`. Precious hint! **3.Others:** other ways are a bit high level for me right now.

Comment: Power and log scales are also available in d3

Comment: Logs will provide me with unconvenient values such 0, 50, 100, 200, 400, 800, 1600, 3200, 6400m. For humans, I prefers to have custom values.